# My character moans, how do I make him stop?

Tags: dayz-standalone

I got hit by a zombie, bled and bandaged myself.

Now my character constantly moans even though I have the healthy status message in my inventory screen. Besides the obvious fact that i've been hit by a zombie, what is the cause for this? It doesn't always happen after being hit.
How can I cure it?

Answer (score 7):

Sir it would appear that you have encountered something called a "**bug**",which is no wonder since DayZ is **early access game**.

This one is known bug and it is even **reported** on the DayZ feedback site so it will be fixed sooner or later...It doesn't seem to have a high priority for now however.

For now **reconnecting should fix** this problem,sadly it isn't viable long term solution.

[Here](http://feedback.dayzgame.com/view.php?id=4578) is the link to the ticket if you want to track the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a DayZ noob but when this happened to me I gave myself a morphine shot and my character shut up. There are also pain relievers. But i guess these are fairly valuable supplies and I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Painkillers, that should fix you right up. Don't use morphine as one person said because that is just a waste. Morphine should only be used for fixing legs, and if you don't have morphine then use a splint. But yah just use some painkillers you can find them in any hospital or even the med tents in bolotta

Answer (score 0):

Your character moaning indicates that they are in pain, regardless of having a healthy status. As far as I can tell, the only downside to being in pain is the noise, which theoretically attracts zombies due to the sound. A number of things can cure this, including the aforementioned painkillers and morphine. I've heard rumors that being fully fed and waiting long enough (a really long time, several days) will help as well, but I've not experienced that myself.

Answer (score -3):

if the sound file is stored on your computer you can try to copy it to a different location.
then rename an soundless sound file (a sound file that has nothing recorded) and rename it to the moaning file name. This will mean however that your character will never moan again.

You also need to figure out which file is the one that causes moaning. You can play them one by one until you hear it and use your deductive skills to skip around (file named kitty.wav will most likely not be it).

Hopefully that helps

Comment: have you even tried this? DayZ does integrity checks on game files, changing anything other than config files might put you at risk of being banned by the anti cheat system.

Comment: doubt it will happen with a sound file but it is possible. I have tried this in multiple other games with some success (even online games). Most integrity checks that i know of dont check for unnecessarily things like sound files. Maybe msging the costumer service and asking them if this is acceptable is the way to go if you are scared of a ban

Comment: I contacted costumer service, I wonder what they have to say about it